# Symfony - There is no extension able to load the configuration - custom config

Tags: symfony

Helo,

i am trying to load custom config into my AppBundle. Unluckily I am getting:

> [Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException]
>   There is no extension able to load the configuration for "app" (in
>   /var/www
>   /dev.investmentopportunities.pl/src/AppBundle/DependencyInjection/../Resour
>   ces/config/general.yml). Looked for namespace "app", found none

There are several similar topics relating to this error. I have looked at them but can't find any solution which would resolve this issue.

My configuration file looks like this:

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Builder\TreeBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\ConfigurationInterface;

class Configuration implements ConfigurationInterface
{
    public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
    {
        $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();
        $rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('app');

         $rootNode
            ->children()
            ->arrayNode('tags')
            ->prototype('array')
                ->children()
                    ->scalarNode('name')->isRequired()->end()
                    ->scalarNode('role')->isRequired()->end()
                    ->scalarNode('priority')->isRequired()->end()
                    ->scalarNode('label')->isRequired()->end()
                ->end()
            ->end();

        return $treeBuilder;
    }
}
```

and **general.yml:**

```
app:
    tags:
        Accepted:
            name: "Accepted"
            role: "ROLE_ACCEPTTAG"
            priority: "3"
            label: "label label-info"
        Booked:
            name: "Booked"
            role: "ROLE_ACCOUNTANT"
            priority: "3"
            label: "label label-info"
        Finalized:
            name: "Booked"
            role: "ROLE_ACCEPTDOC"
            priority: "1"
            label: "label label-success"
```

**AppExtension.php:**

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Extension\PrependExtensionInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\Extension;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Tests\Fixtures\Entity;

/**
 * This is the class that loads and manages your bundle configuration
 */
class AppExtension extends Extension
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $configuration = new Configuration();
        $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

        $container->setParameter('app', $config['app']);

        $loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
        $loader->load('general.yml'); # another file of yours

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: You should not load your `general.yml` file in the extension.

Defining a configuration for a bundle is about how the bundle will handle configuration, understand the configuration coming from `config.yml`.

So you should import your `general.yml` file in the `config.yml` and it should work.

Note: Loaders are from `Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader` namespace, they are for dependency injection, to allow a bundle to define services, mostly used by third-party bundles.